# How to add elements of an array to another array's element in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, higher-order-functions

```swift
let prices = [11, 22, 12, 32, 1, 5, 26] //this is a collection of initial prices of some items

let increasingAmount = prices.map{($0 * 0.5)} //this constant stores the amount the initial price will increase
```

I would like to add the increasingAmount to prices to get the new price for each item:

```swift
let prices =           [11,   22, 12, 32, 1,   5,   26]
let increasingAmount = [5.5,  11, 6,  16, 0.5, 2.5, 13]
let newPrices =        [16.5, 33, 38, 17, 5.5, 7.5, 39] //this is the desired output that i would like to achieve.
```

I could just modify the multiply value from 0.5 to 1.5 but I don't want that approach.

Comment: You can zip the two arrays and then use map to get the sum of the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [`zip`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/zip(_:_:)) method which is going to return a sequence of tuple pairs of kind `(prices_i, increasingAmount_i)` and then use `map` to sum the elements

```swift
let prices = [11.0, 22.0, 12.0, 32.0, 1.0, 5.0, 26.0]
let increasingAmount = [5.5, 11, 6, 16, 0.5, 2.5, 13]
var newPrices: [Double] = zip(prices, increasingAmount).map { $0 + $1 }
// or shorter
newPrices = zip(prices, increasingAmount).map(+)

print(newPrices) // [16.5, 33, 38, 17, 5.5, 7.5, 39]
```

Note that you have to specify the type of `newPrices` because the swift compiler interprets `prices` array as `[Int]` and `increasingAmount` as `[Double]` and it has to know what you want `newPrices` to be.

This will work even if the arrays have different sizes, in that case `zip` will ignore the extra elements in the longest array.

You can play around with this [here](https://swiftfiddle.com/bxs7djokv5cgbeizt7s3epb6zi)